# terms checkbox missing in checkout

Tags: magento2, checkout, terms-and-conditions

In `Magento 2.1.7` when arrive to the payment checkout there is a line for the terms: **I accept the terms and conditions** but there is no checkbox.

When I click on pay button it displays an error message that I have to accept the terms, but I can't accept them without checkbox!

In

```
magento_root/vendor/magento/module-checkout-agreements/view/frontend/web/template/checkout/checkout-agreements.html
```

can see the code:

```
<div data-role="checkout-agreements">
<div class="checkout-agreements" data-bind="visible: isVisible">
    <!-- ko foreach: agreements -->
        <!-- ko if: ($parent.isAgreementRequired($data)) -->
        <div class="checkout-agreement">
            <input type="checkbox"
                   data-bind="attr: {
                                'id': 'agreement_' + agreementId,
                                'name': 'agreement[' + agreementId + ']',
                                'value': agreementId
                                }"
                   data-validate="{required:true}" />
            <label data-bind="attr: {'for': 'agreement_' + agreementId}">
                <button type="button"
                        class="action action-show"
                        data-bind="click: function(data, event) { return $parent.showContent(data, event) }"
                        >
                    <span data-bind="html: checkboxText"></span>
                </button>
            </label>
        </div>
        <!-- /ko -->
        <!-- ko ifnot: ($parent.isAgreementRequired($data)) -->
        <div class="checkout-agreement">
            <button type="button" class="action action-show"
                    data-bind="click: function(data, event) { return $parent.showContent(data, event) }">
                <span data-bind="html: checkboxText"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <!-- /ko -->
    <!-- /ko -->
    <div id="checkout-agreements-modal" data-bind="afterRender: initModal" style="display: none">
        <div class="checkout-agreements-item-content" data-bind="html: modalContent"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

but in the web there is:

```
<div data-role="checkout-agreements">
<div class="checkout-agreements" data-bind="visible: isVisible">
    <!-- ko foreach: agreements -->
        <!-- ko if: ($parent.isAgreementRequired($data)) --><!-- /ko -->
        <!-- ko ifnot: ($parent.isAgreementRequired($data)) -->
        <div class="checkout-agreement">
            <button type="button" class="action action-show" data-bind="click: function(data, event) { return $parent.showContent(data, event) }">
                <span data-bind="html: checkboxText">I accept terms and conditions</span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <!-- /ko -->
    <!-- /ko -->

</div>
```

So all the code that references the checkbox input is missing.

I have configured in `admin panel -> stores/terms` and conditions the terms with status enabled and applied automatically.

I have configured in `admin panel -> stores/configuration/sales/order/payment process options` **the terms and conditions enabled**.

As I configured the terms and conditions in both places it should display the checkbox, but there is no checkbox.

Is like the `ko if: ($parent.isAgreementRequired($data))` is false always.

I cleared the cache several times: `php bin/magento cache:flush`

I reindexed: `php bin/magento indexer:reindex`

I made a **setup upgrade**, `setup di compile and setup deploy static` but still no checkbox.

Finally I tried disabling all the terms and conditions, but still can't pay. Not sure what's happening as the code of the checkout remains untouched yet.

Answer (score 6):

You have to go in `Store Menu > Sales Checkout Agreements`

- Select the agreements terms you want to make required by clicking on its row
- In the Apply combobox(select) : select the Manually option.

Then refresh your `checkout_index_index` page (checkout OPC) and you'll see the checkbox before the "Checkbox text".

The `Apply` option makes the Terms auto accept if automatic or Need to check the checkbox if manually ;)

Comment: Please check this issue code too, you need to create your own 

- Magento_CheckoutAgreements/web/js/checkout-agreements.js 

and 

- Magento_CheckoutAgreements/web/template/checkout/checkout-agreements.html 

in your theme, cuse if you use multiple payment methods you'll be stucked by a non fixed issue of unique checkbox ID.

Check the code here : (replace entire file in your custom theme)

https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/14b9b9813c9a16c0c45505885503cfb71bc4eb8d

Comment: I have enabled terms and conditions but after that not able to place order if selected checkbox.

Answer (score 5):

In the Magento `Stores->Setting->Terms and Conditions` open the your condition and in `applied field` dropdown you can `set the Manually` than you are get the checkbox at the frontend.

if not get than run the commnad

```
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this issue in the blank theme by adding 20px to the CSS box in: Stores -> Terms and Conditions -> You Terms.